# OHLC chart in javafx

Tags: java, charts, javafx-2, finance, javafx-8

I want to make OHLC chart in javaFx. I have seen esemble program given in oracle but it does not give OHLC chart example.
I have gone through candlestick chart but what I need is ohlc charts
http://www.cesix.inifap.gob.mx/frutalestropicales/map/anychart/help/docs/img/Samples/Sample-Single-Series-OHLC-Chart.png

Please if anyone has any idea or any example anything, please help.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

[JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) works in JavaFX now, and supports OHLC charts.

Answer (score 0):

Seems, OHLC charts don't exist for JavaFX 2.+.

And they are not planned for javafx 8+.

So you need to develop them yourself, or wait for/look for third-party solution.

Comment: is there any other way to do it with javafx,
I have candlestick code. Am trying with css to do it.

Comment: I think, you are trying right. If they are mathematically equivalent, you can reach the success. Possibly, you will have to patch the code of candle stick chart for that.